# How do item loadings in PCA / FA relate to the true factors in an instrument?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, confirmatory-factor

My question relates to a real research problem I am having. I am going to do EFA (well actually PCA) on a 111 item questionnaire designed to screen for 20 different disorders found in childhood and adolescence. Incidentally, I am going to use Velicer's MAP test to decide number of factors to extract. My search of the relevant literature tells me that my PCA will likely reveal fewer factors than the instrument claims to have.

My problem is I don't fully understand item loading. I know that the items may not load as they should but I don't understand why.

- Is it because the items may measure multiple factors?
- Also, can some items just load nowhere?
- Can a completely new factor(s) emerge that might be comprised of all (or most of) all of the items of say, two factors?

Comment: Why are you doing PCA rather than FA? And, if you are trying to confirm the number of factors, why not do confirmatory factor analysis?

If you actually do PCA, then you get principal components.

Yes, any of the things you mention could happen.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am doing PCA because the scale is scored by a unitary procedure (ie you add up the scores), so I am reliably advised that this fact necessitates PCA.

Comment: I don't know why that would be the case. PCA is about dimension reduction. FA is about finding latent factors. Sounds like you want the latter.

Comment: I agree with Peter Flom. I don't see how equal weight summation leads to favoring PCA. You would want to check Peter Bentler's work on how these simple sums work: http://www.google.com/search?q=peter+bentler+unit+weighted+composites

Comment: Um well I am out of my depth here. The advice I am given is "If you use common factor solution to explore the factor structure of the scale, then you need to use factor scoring to score the scale. If the scales are scored by a unitary procedure (ie. you add up the scores), then you need to use PCA to determine what the factors are. If you want a scale to be able to be hand scored by clinicians (or even a program), then you should use PCA, which will show the factor structure that is closest to the actually (sic) scoring of the scales. See next comment  for final bit as ran out of characters

Comment: ...You can use common factor methods if you intend to use weighted scoring (ie for evetry item you multiply the reponse by the beta weight obtained from the factor anaysis) before you add the scores"